# Date format in iPhone 4 app not changed when changing Region Format in Settings

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Changing the region format on an iPhone 4 does not change the date and number format in my app until the iPhone is switched off and on again (or the app is terrminated in another way).

Is there a way to detect Region Format changes in UIApplicationDelegate::OnActivated?

I can reset my app there, but it seems that DateTime::ToShortDateString() still is using the old region settings. Is it possible to change that?

Comment: I would assume that with IOS4+, because the app doesn't actually terminate, any global settings (such as region) wouldn't be updated until the application is re-launched. Optionally, you could set the app to behave as an IOS3.x app and close when resigning active status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel's suggestion to use NSDate and NSDateFormatter partially solves the problem: after changing the region format when the program is re-activated AND you change the view, NSDateFormatter is aware of the new locale. At that time NSLocale.CurrentLocale also returns the correct locale for the region format.

Of course, any dates which were alreay formatted are still in the old format, including the form which is shown when the program is activated. To resolve this, the program must detect the change in the region format when it is re-activated, and reset all views if changed. Logically this should be done during the applicationDidBecomeActive event.

**Surprisingly, when UIApplicationDelegate::OnActivated (applicationDidBecomeActive) is called, NSLocale.CurrentLocale still returns the OLD locale and NSDateFormatter is not yet aware of the new format!**

I'm not sure when they become aware of the new format. When you change to another view they are aware of the new format. The iPhone Mail app imediately detects the new region format on re-activation, so there shoud be a way to detect it at program activation. Maybe a NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification event is raised after applicationDidBecomeActive, but this event is not available in monotouch.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I rather use NSDate and NSDateFormatter for date conversions and user representation even under Monotouch apps with DateTime available as it seems to me better tight up with iOS.

This is beautiful thing with Monotouch, you can always rely on iOS SDK as usual.

Hope this helps.